# Linux run every program on cluster

Tags: debian, cluster

I am playing around with Open MPI and I must say I love the concept of running programs on the cluster.

The problem I am facing with Open MPI is that a specific program must support this way of executing.

Is there another option where I am able to run ANY program on the cluster without having to deal with these restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also MPICH and Boost MPT but that's probably not what you're meaning.

You're probably wanting to know if it's possible to run any arbitrary program across an HPC cluster. The answer is no and just because of how execution of an executable program actually works.

These systems are intended to solve the problem of how you divide the workload between the worker nodes. There has the be some sort of software infrastructure for the nodes to receive their work, share the results, and repeat the cycle.

If you're interested in working around a particular problem you're having with OpenMPI you might post to Stack Overflow.